Classify the group $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})/\langle(1,1)\rangle$

Classify the group $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_3)/\langle(1,1)\rangle$ according to the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

My Attempt
\begin{align}
G=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_3\quad\&\quad H&=\langle(1,1)\rangle=\{k,k\mod 3|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\\
\text{Cosets of }\langle(1,1)\rangle\text{ in }\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_3&=(a,b)+\langle(1,1)\rangle\\
&=\{a+k,b+k\mod 3|(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_3\}\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)\in (a,b)+H\\
&\implies (a_1-a_2,b_1-b_2)=(k,k\mod 3)\\
&\implies b_1-b_2=k\mod 3=(a_1-a_2)\mod 3
\end{align}
It is tempting to say that there are three kinds of cosets and therefore the cardinality of $G/H$ is 3, and therefore isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$. But, I think the cardinality is not 3, but rather infinite. So I got to define a homomorphism $\phi:G\to G'$ with $ker(\phi)=H$ to show that $G/H\cong Im(\phi)$. Intuition says, it may be $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_3$.
What exactly is the right way to think about it?

Thanks @Anne Bauval for the hint!
\begin{align}
b_1-b_2=(a_1-a_2)\mod 3\implies (b_1-b_2)-(a_1-a_2)=0\mod 3\\
(b_1-a_1)-(b_2-a_2)=0\mod 3\implies (b_1-a_1)=(b_2-a_2)\mod 3
\end{align}
There are essentially 3 cosets corresponds to $0\mod 3,1\mod 3, 2\mod 3$, ie., $|(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_3)/\langle(1,1)\rangle|=3$. This implies that $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_3)/\langle(1,1)\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}_3$

Your first answer was correct. What makes you "think the cardinality is not 3, but rather infinite"? $G/H\cong\Bbb Z^2/\langle(0,3),(1,1)\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_3$.

Note that $(a,b)+H=(0,b-a)+(a,a) +H$. But $(a,a) \in H$. So, any $(a,b) \equiv (0,b-a) \mod H$. Note that $b-a \in \mathbb{Z}_3$. This implies there are $3$ distinct cosets.

And if you want confirmation using a homomorphism, consider the map from $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z_3$ to $\Bbb Z_3$ defined by $f(a,b) = b-a$. But you're in the process of training your intuition, so don't feel bad!

@AnneBauval a coset is $a+H={a+h|h\in H}$. $H=\langle(1,1)\rangle$ has infinite elements. And $Z$ has infinite cardinality, and therefore for each member from the infinite members of $Z\times Z_3$, we can obtain individual cosets. Thus, don't we have infinite cosets?

@AnneBauval Two elements $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ are int he same coset if $(a_1-a_2,b_1-b_2)=(k,k\mod 3)\implies b_1-b_2=k\mod 3=(a_1-a_2)\mod 3$ right ? from there can I obtain that expression ? Sorry, am I just missing some modular arithmetic here ?

You are correct.

This question is very likely to be a duplicate, the quotient can be calculated for all numbers. Instead of posting answers in the comments or answers, experienced users should use site search to mark it as duplicate. See also Enforcement of quality standards. Also please remember that the comment section is not a chat. See How do comments work for more information

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.

Let $u=(0,1),v=(1,1)\in\Bbb Z^2$.
$G/H\cong\Bbb Z^2/\langle(0,3),(1,1)\rangle=(\Bbb Zu\oplus\Bbb Zv)/(
\Bbb Z(3u)\oplus\Bbb Zv)\cong(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)\oplus0.$

We have
$$G\cong \langle x,y\mid y^3=e, xy=yx\rangle$$
and so $H\cong\langle\langle xy\rangle\rangle_G$, where $\langle\langle xy\rangle\rangle_G$ is the normal subgroup of $G$ generated by $xy$; you can see this by viewing $x=(1,[0]_3)$ and $y=(0,[1]_3)$.
Then, by definition of a presentation, we have
$$\begin{align}
G/H&\cong\langle x,y\mid y^3=e, xy=yx\rangle/\langle\langle xy\rangle\rangle_G\\
&\cong\langle x,y\mid y^3=e, xy=yx, xy=e\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y\mid y^3=e, xy=yx, y=x^{-1}\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x\mid (x^{-1})^3=e, e=e\rangle\\
&\cong \langle x\mid e=x^3\rangle\\
&\cong\Bbb Z_3
\end{align}$$
by Tietze transformations.
